# Children view controllers must have a common parent view controller?

Tags: ios, ios5, view, uiviewcontroller, transition

In my app I am attempting to switch views which each is their own XIB while using custom animations to do so. I made a base view controller as a parent view to hold all the code but I just can't seem to get this to work.

I made an IBOutlet for all of the view controllers in my app and in interface builder, I connect the outlets to the proper controller. Each controller loads the proper XIB too so none of that is the issue. The issue is the following changing views code.

This is my code:

```
-(void)changeViews {
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(frame);
    theView4.view.frame = frame;

    [self.view addSubview:theView4.view];
    [self addChildViewController:theView4];

    [self transitionFromViewController:theView1 
                      toViewController:theView4 
                              duration:1 
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                            animations: ^{
                                CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
                                theView4.view.frame = frame;
                                frame.origin.x -= frame.size.width;
                                self.view.frame = frame;
                            }
                            completion:completion:nil];
```

And this is the console crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Children view controllers <MyGameViewController: 0x1dd25210> and <Settings: 0x1dd249d0> must have a common parent view controller when calling -[UIViewController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:]'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the "Settings" class? How is it defined?

Comment: The settings class is a UIViewController that is declared in the header file, settered and gettered and is connect to a View Controller outlet in Interface Builder which is connected to the Settings nib and class via its attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

> When you use `addChildViewController:` to add the child view
>   controller to the surrounding one. You also have to notify the child
>   controller by `didMoveToViewController:` that it has been put into
>   another controller. You can also use
>   `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:` to exchange one view
>   controller for another, optionally giving an animation.

This was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084050/when-to-use-addchildviewcontroller-vs-pushviewcontroller) (I would advise you to fully read the accepted answer).

Long story short, you also need to inform that it did move into that parent view controller.