# ScrollView with Paging

Tags: ios

I have added 3 `UIViewController` in my ScrollView , like this

```
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view3"]];
```

How can i find which is visible ?

Comment: i don't know your question but this tutorial would be helpful to you http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2013/01/page-control-for-switching-between-views.html

Answer (score 0):

You only use `- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController` to build your own containment view controller (e.g. your own tabBarController), not to add a subview to a scrollview. For more information on view controller containment you should read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html and for a short summary you could read [When to use addChildViewController vs pushViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084050/when-to-use-addchildviewcontroller-vs-pushviewcontroller)

If you want to add a view to a scrollview, you should simply use `- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view` (e.g. `[self.scrollView addSubview:viewOfViewControllerWithIdentifierView1]`). Also make sure you set the scrollviews contentSize and the subviews frame. However, if you want a scrollview to page between different view controllers, I'd recommend you take a look at UIPageViewController: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by the calculating the contentoffset of you scroll view. For this You have to add the Delegate Methode of Scrollview.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    page_control.currentPage=scrollView.contentOffset.x/320;
}
```

In above code I have multiple ChildView controller having Width of 320px means complete iPhone screen width. And **page_control** is the Page Controller for Which I'm selecting the current Page.

Let me ask If you have any confusion.